# How to install older versions of google api in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to install google api android api 4 but it is not showing it in available packages.How can I install it?Right now I have google ap1 android api 9 installed,I want lower version to be installed on my system.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be under the Android SDK / AVD Manager under available packages.   I believe it's under the Third Party Add-ons.  Just press the icon on the left to expand the list.  I have Google API 3 to 13 installed on mine.

Take care,
Shannon

Comment: I tried the same thing,it is showing no updates(no google api).Though I have installed google api 9 to 12 but I want to install lower version.Please tell me what's going wrong ?